# to view route between two points in map +iphone+Mapkit

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

i want to get the route between the two point in the mapkit!
i had done some google work n found this :-http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108

I had used this to display map and pin:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    self.title=@"Map";  
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location; 
    location.latitude=[latLabel doubleValue];
    location.longitude=[longLabel doubleValue]; 
    MKCoordinateRegion region;// = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((location.latitude) / 2.0, (location.longitude) / 2.0), 1000.0, 1000.0);
    region.center=location;
    region.span.latitudeDelta =0.1;
    region.span.longitudeDelta =0.1;
    addAnnotation=[[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];      
    NSLog(@"city=mapview=>%@",City);
    NSLog(@"adress=mapview=>%@",Address);   
    addAnnotation.title=City;
    addAnnotation.subtitle=Address;
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];  
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];        
    }

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(AddressAnnotation *) annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;   
    annView.draggable=TRUE; 
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout=YES;
    annView.calloutOffset=CGPointMake(-5,5);
    annView.draggable=TRUE;
    return annView;
}
```

And annotation class to display the name and address.But how should i have to add more to display  the route between the two points.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to invoke google's direction services. Read the documentation at

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Use the URL that suits your need. Then you would need a JSON or XML parser. JSON has an API, you can download it here

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

You can then get your route polyline points using:

```
if (error == nil) {
        NSError *JSONError = nil;
        SBJsonParser *JSONParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
        id  directions = [JSONParser objectWithString:directionsInJSON error:&JSONError];
        if (JSONError == nil) {
            directions = (NSDictionary*)directions;
            //NSLog(@"Directions: %@",directions);

            NSString *status = [directions objectForKey:@"status"];
            if ([status isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
                gotDirections = YES;
                NSArray *routes = [directions objectForKey:@"routes"];
                NSDictionary *route = [routes objectAtIndex:0];
                NSDictionary *polylineOverview = [route objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];

                NSString *polylinePoints = [polylineOverview objectForKey:@"points"];
                NSArray *decodedPolyline = [self decodePolyLine:polylinePoints];
            }
        }
}
//handle elses

- (NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSString *)encoded {
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] autorelease];
        NSNumber *longitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] autorelease];
        CLLocation *loc = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] autorelease];
        [array addObject:loc];
    }

    return array;
}

Then display this array using mkpolyline:

CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[[routes count]];
        for(int i = 0; i < route.count; i++) {        
            CLLocation* location = (CLLocation*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[routes objectAtIndex:i]];         
            CLLocationCoordinate2D c;
            c.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
            c.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;        
            coords[i] = c; 

            Annotation *ann = [[Annotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"" Subtitle:@"" andCoordinate:c];
            [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
            [ann release];
        }

        MKPolyline *line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D*)coords count:[route count]];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:line];
```

Also implement mapView:viewForOverlay delegate method:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {

        MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        polylineView.lineWidth = 1.5;
        return polylineView;
    }

    return [[MKOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
}
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for this solution! It works great for me , with one little detail...it crashes :P . On this line: CLLocation* location = (CLLocation*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[routes objectAtIndex:i]]; . The error log says "[CLLocation bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" . Do you have any idea what might be wrong? I am getting the list of steps from google and there are 47 decoded points in my array but this unarchiveObjectWithData call makes the app crash. Please let me know if you have any idea why. Thanks again for the solution. Regards, George

Comment: @George the unarchiving is prob there because i must have archived the data earlier. If your using directly you wont need that.